# Is this on-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, specific-question

I asked [Planet feed aggregator for django](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9110/planet-feed-aggregator-for-django) yesterday and it has only received 2 views. I've now improved the question a fair bit in case that was the reason for the low view count.

However, this is m first time using this site so I was wondering does this perhaps indicate my question is off-topic here? If so, is there a better site to ask it on?

Answer (score 1):

Low views suggests your title is the problem because it means people didn't even look at the question. It follows therefore that improving the question itself won't attract more views.

Sometimes you need to shy away from an overly specific title, even if it does in fact describe the question well. People who don't read the question obviously are not going to post answers, so the first step is to try and get them to read the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what your question is asking, and it seems awfully django specific which is a strong hint that it's not very webmaster-centric.

(webmaster questions typically don't relate to specific programming languages but rather the fabric of the web and general html / css things.)

Comment: I'm trying to explain it as best I can, but I'm not very experienced at web development. The best answers probably aren't going to be django-specific, but you're probably right about it being off-topic (which is why I asked). I don't think it fits on SO either?